# Count in s Table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I like to create a simple query to count number of similar values in a column. Example is here below

```
declare @temo table (sno int identity, dyscode varchar(200), isVerified bit, isCorrect bit, isRejected bit, isDeleted bit)

insert into @temo values('dys',1,1,0,0)
insert into @temo values('dys',1,1,0,0)
insert into @temo values('dys',1,0,1,0)
insert into @temo values('dys',1,0,0,1)
insert into @temo values('dys',1,0,1,0)
insert into @temo values('dys',1,0,0,1)
insert into @temo values('dys',0,0,0,0)
insert into @temo values('dys',1,0,0,1)
```

Expected Output Should be

> 'dys',7,2,3

Please share some quick and efficient solutions for the same. This operations needs to be run on millions of records, so performance will be a great concern.

Comment: Shouldn't your output be `dys,7,2,2,3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needs to cast the bit columns to do sum function on them because sum function does not support bit data type.

Link for Reference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187810.aspx

Below query will the required result :-

```
SELECT   dyscode,
     sum(cast(isVerified as int)),
     sum(cast(isCorrect as int)),
     sum(cast(isRejected as int)),
     sum(cast(isDeleted as int))
FROM     @temo
GROUP BY dyscode
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're just summing the 0/1 columns:

```
SELECT   dyscode,
         SUM(isVerified),
         SUM(isCorrect),
         SUM(isRejected),
         SUM(isDeleted)
FROM     @temo
GROUP BY dyscode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Select dyscode, 
sum(isVerified), 
sum(isCorrect), 
sum(isRejected), 
sum(isDeleted)
        From 
        @temo
    Group by dyscode
```

Use sum function since values are binary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to group on the dyscode column and sum of other column.

You can use below query.

```
Select dyscode ,SUM(isVerified),SUM(isCorrect),SUM(isRejected),SUM(isDeleted) from #temo group by dyscode
```